# UFT One AIUtil Wildcard

Tags: hp-uft

I am using the AIUtil functionality to select an option in a pop up and then click the ok button.  The issue is interacting with the options within the popup.

The code is: `AIUtil.FindTextBlock("some text").Click`

Some text is variable based on the user but he beginning of the text always starts with the same word.  So My thought is to use a wildcard and try that.  I cannot find anything online that tells me how to do this or if it is even possible.

I've tried passing the constant plus a regular expression but that didn't work either.

So I thought I would reach out to anyone who uses UFT to find out if they know.  Thanks in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

For partial text you can use [`FindText`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/2021-2022/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/AI/AIPackageLib%7EAIUtil.html#FindText) instead of `FindTextBlock`.

```
AIUtil.FindText("some text").Click
```